# Junit 5, Spring Application Context does not close on @DirtiesContext

Tags: java, spring, selenium-webdriver, junit, junit5

My application context is not closed after test method.
I use Junit 5.3.1, spring 5.1.0.RELEASE for Selenium WebDriver tests.

This is my bean:

```
@Configuration
public class WebDriverConfig {

// ... Some Code ...

@Bean(destroyMethod = "quit")
    @Primary
    public DelegatingWebDriver cleanWebDriver(WebDriver driver) throws Exception {
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        return new DelegatingWebDriver(driver);
    }

// ... Some more code ...
}
```

This is my class:

```
 @ExtendWith({SpringExtension.class})
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { WebDriverConfig.class, LoggerConfig.class, EmailConfig.class})
@TestExecutionListeners(listeners= {ScreenshotTaker.class, DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, TestListener.class})
@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public class BasicScenariosIT {

    @Inject
    private DelegatingWebDriver driver;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @Inject
    private URI baseUrl;

    @Inject
    private Logger logger;

    private DelegatingExtentTest testCase;

// ... Some tests ...
}
```

I expect the line:

> @DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)

to close the application context and fire up the line:

> @Bean(destroyMethod = "quit")

In my case, call method "quit" close the browser and start a new one. However it doesn't seem to happen. 
Would appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a workaround.
I implemented spring test listeners, and in the listener I marked the context as dirty, instead of relying on the `@DirtiesContext` annotation. 
The listener looks like this:

```
@ExtendWith({SpringExtension.class})
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { WebDriverConfig.class, LoggerConfig.class})
@TestExecutionListeners(listeners= {DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class})
public class RunnerExtension extends AbstractTestExecutionListener {


    @Autowired
    protected Logger logger;

    @Autowired
    protected DelegatingWebDriver driver;

    @Override
    public void beforeTestClass(TestContext testContext) throws Exception {
        testContext.getApplicationContext()
                .getAutowireCapableBeanFactory()
                .autowireBean(this);        
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTestMethod(TestContext testContext) throws Exception {
        // .. some code here ..
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTestExecution(TestContext testContext) throws Exception {
        // .. some code here .. 
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTestExecution(TestContext testContext) throws Exception {
        // .. some code here ..
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTestMethod(TestContext testContext) throws IOException {

        // .. some code here ..

        testContext.markApplicationContextDirty(HierarchyMode.EXHAUSTIVE);

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTestClass(TestContext testContext) throws IOException {
        // .. some code here ..

    }
}
```

The important code line is:

> testContext.markApplicationContextDirty(HierarchyMode.EXHAUSTIVE);

It marks the context as dirty and a new context will be created in the next session.

Comment: Is this fixed in Spring Boot 2.2 or is it still a bug? Do you have a GitHub issue link?